# Whitelisting IP address of shared hosting on MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am currently connecting to MongoDB on Atlas server through my shared hosting website using PHP.
Everything works great as long as I have 0.0.0.0/0 whitelisted ( any ip ), but it is a security vulnerability.

I cannot seem to find the correct IP address to whitelist, so I can disable the "any ip" option.
I've pinged my website address in cmd, I've grabbed my ip from $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'], I've used whois data to get an ip address, and checked cloudflare for an ip address.

It doesn't seem that any address I use works.

MongoDB has an activity log that logs IP addresses, but it only logs activity done on the site in the browser, not anything done through remote access...

Has anyone figured this out already?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways this can be done:

1. Ask your hosting company what IP addresses or range(s) they use for their application servers, whitelist those.
2. Look through mongod log, it logs all incoming connections. Locate the ones from your application, get the actual IP addresses used, add those to the whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way is to use `curl portquiz.net:27017` in your SSH window, or with a curl command:

```
    <?php
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "portquiz.net:27017");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 
        echo $output;       
     ?>
```